# Week dimension in case of month split

Tags: sql-server, olap-cube

For example In year 2024 week 9 splits into two months

| PK_Date | Month | Month_Of_Year | Week | Week_Name | Week_Of_Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-26 | 00:00:00.000 | 2024-02-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 2024-02-26 | vko.9 |
| 2024-02-27 | 00:00:00.000 | 2024-02-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 2024-02-26 | vko.9 |
| 2024-02-28 | 00:00:00.000 | 2024-02-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 2024-02-26 | vko.9 |
| 2024-02-29 | 00:00:00.000 | 2024-02-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 2024-02-26 | vko.9 |
| 2024-03-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 2024-03-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 2024-02-25 | vko.9 |
| 2024-03-02 | 00:00:00.000 | 2024-03-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 2024-02-25 | vko.9 |
| 2024-03-03 | 00:00:00.000 | 2024-03-01 | 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 2024-02-25 | vko.9 |

If I make date dimension with attribute relationships

PK Date -> Week Of Year - Year

Hierarchy shows week 9 only once (just like customer wants)

However If I add Month of year to attribute relationships week 9 splits into two nodes in hierarchy.

[image]

Customer wants to use month as a filter. How to solve this so hierarchy shows week 9 only once

Comment: Solution for this was that for some reason there was error in generated contents of time table. Like show above whole week should have same week start date ( 00:00:00.000 2 2024-02-26). Now march dates had  incorrect value 00:00:00.000 3 2024-02-25

Regards

Cazzy